# Tilemap array in AS3

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, mysqli

I have created a tilemap in AS3 that I need to save to a database, the system works absolutely fine. When the user creates an account, a map is automatically created for them (it's always the same sized map, with trees, rocks etc 11x11).

```
[18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17],
[3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17],
[7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5],
```

How do I go about saving this to a mysqli database and then get the information and return it back to the AS3 script? I know how to post from AS3, and I know how to get information from a page. I've saved the entire Array under one Column called tileMap, then when I try and query tileMap from the table... nothing is returned. Is it because I am using the `[ ]` braces? I don't really know how to go about displaying this.

Comment: Use JSON conversion back and forth.

Comment: @Naythan You can also optimize your data : `[18,20x19,20],[3,10x0,11,9x0,17],[3,10x0,9,9x0,17],[3,20x0, 17] ... ` ...

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize/deserialize your data, IMHO keep data for database in JSON format would be nice, cause it's easy to convert such a data in Object ()
hence in Array too).

```
//this function converts data from Array to Object, we need Object for easy JSON conversation afterwards
function toObject(array:Array):Object
{
        var obj:Object = {};
        for (var i:int = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
        {
            obj[i] = array[i];
        }
        return obj;
}

//this converts Object To Array 
function toArray(obj:Object):Array
{
        var arr:Array = [];
        for (var i in obj)
        {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i))
            {
                arr.push(obj[i]);
            }
        }
        return arr;
}

//it's you array
var arr:Array = [[18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 17], [7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 5]];

var jsonString:String = JSON.stringify(toObject(arr)); //we got JSON string which for example could be saved as TEXT data in MySQL via PHP      
var onceMoreArray:Array=toArray(JSON.parse(jsonString)); //We can convert JSON string back to array
```

Hope this method would help.

Comment: I'm gonna have to vote this down. Good try though but Object unfortunately does not retain indexes and the whole system would break completely. The JSON format works fine with array so no need to convert an Array to an object.

Comment: Results are the same in this case, thanks for the notes and downvote, but additionally, please, edit my code and write down correct answer.

Comment: I was actually looking for how to store the data into a database, but also how to read it again and insert it back into an array exactly how it is saved as.

Answer (score 0):

Create a string from your matrix.

```
[1,0,2],
[2,3,4],
[0,1,5]
```

become

```
1:0:2|2:3:4|0:1:5
```

To read you can use the split function, first with '|' and then with ':'